# angular flex layout responsive form central align in desktop and left align in mobile device

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, responsive-design

i have basic html like this by this lib : https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

```
<div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">
        <label class="f_label margintop">Sports </label>
        <input type="number" matInput>
</div>
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">
            <label class="f_label margintop">Country </label>
            <input type="number" matInput>
</div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">
            <label class="f_label margintop">IsActive? </label>
            <input type="number" matInput>
</div>
        </div>
```

#1: what i really want is in desktop ( larger device ), i want label and input as centrally align,

i.e - in row - Label should be align to right : and input align to left.

#2: and mobile both should be left align.

something like this - image uploaded to imgur.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrvgE.jpg

what i tried so far is :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-wqeqvc?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="center center"`:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="center center">
```